# Invalid column name for @Version in Hibernate Entity Object

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to implement optimistick lock in my entity object. I googled and found adding below will keep track version. But may be I am missing some hibernate configuration cause I am getting following error. Any help appreciated!

```
@version
private int version;
```

> Error:- Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3965)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:299)

Comment: Pls post your configuration and update the question with full stacktrace.

Comment: How are you running your code? Please also post the code where you try tp perform CRUD operations on your entity.